# Ajax request not return branches drop down List based on company drop down list selected value?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I working on MVC razor page with .NET core 7 .I face issue Ajax request not return branches drop down list based on selected value from drop down list company .

with another meaning I need cascade branch drop down list based on company drop down list by using ajax request .

so data display data on branches drop down list will be

```
select iBranchCode,vBranchDesc from branchs  where companyno=companyno (selected value on drop down list company)
```

I try but not give me result

1-create model branches

```
public class Branch
    {
        [Key]
        public string iBranchCode { get; set; }
        public string vBranchDesc { get; set; }
        public string CompanyNo { get; set; }
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    }
```

2- on razor page `AddUser.cshtml.cs`

```
public class AddUserModel : PageModel
    {
    [BindProperty]
    public UC.ADC.Core.Entities.SQL.User  User { get; set; }
    private readonly ADCContext _db;
        public AddUserModel(ADCContext db)
        {
            _db = db;
            userModel = new AddUserViewModel();
          
        }
  public void OnGet()
        {
            userModel.Branches  = _db.Branch.ToList();
            userModel.Companies = GetCompanies();
        }
public JsonResult GetRelatedBranches(string companyId)
        {
            var Branches = _db.Branch.Where(p => p.CompanyNo == companyId).ToList();

            return new JsonResult(Branches); 
          
        }
    }
```

3-on html page of `AddUser.cshtml`

```
@page "/AddUser"
@model UC.ADC.Host.Pages.Users.AddUserModel
 <form method="post">
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="company-select" class="col-sm-1 col-form-label" style="font-size:15px;font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;font-weight: bold;">Company</label>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <select id="company-select" asp-for="User.CompanyNo" class="form-control" style=" margin-left:10px;font-size:15px;font-family: 'Open Sans' , sans-serif;font-weight: bold;">
                    <option value="">-- Select Company --</option>
                     @foreach (var company in Model.userModel.Companies)
                     {
       
                        <option value="@company.CompanyNo">@company.CompanyName</option>


                     }
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="branch-select" class="col-sm-1 col-form-label" style="font-size:15px;font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;font-weight: bold;">Branch</label>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <select id="branch-select" asp-for="User.iBranchCode" class="form-control" style=" margin-left:10px;font-size:15px;font-family: 'Open Sans' , sans-serif;font-weight: bold;">
                    <option value="">-- Select Branch --</option>
                 @*   @(model.br == branch.Id ? "selected" : "")*@
                     @foreach (var branch in Model.userModel.Branches)
                    {
                        <option value="@branch.iBranchCode">@branch.vBranchDesc</option>
                    }
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
@section scripts {
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#company-select').change(function () {
                var companyId = $(this).val();
                console.log("company id is" + companyId)
                if (companyId) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '@Url.Action("GetRelatedBranches", "AddUserModel")',
                        type: "GET",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: { companyId: companyId },
                        success: function (data) {
                            console.log("data  is" + data);
                            $('#branch-select').empty();
                            $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                                $('#branch-select').append($('<option>', {
                                    value: item.iBranchCode,
                                    text: item.vBranchDesc
                                }));
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    </script> 
}
```

**Expected result when select company then select branches list related must show based on company no**
[image: issues branches not generated based on company select]

**Update post**
issue on ajax request below :

```
@section scripts {
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#company-select').change(function () {
                var companyId = $(this).val();
                console.log("company id is" + companyId)
                if (companyId) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '@Url.Action("GetRelatedBranches", "AddUserModel")',
                        type: "GET",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: { companyId: companyId },
                        success: function (data) {
                            console.log("data  is" + data);
                            $('#branch-select').empty();
                            $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                                $('#branch-select').append($('<option>', {
                                    value: item.iBranchCode,
                                    text: item.vBranchDesc
                                }));
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    </script> 
}
```

Comment: Does your `console.log(data)` return the data you expect it to return? Is this data formatted correctly?

Comment: thanks for reply where i can put console.log(data)

Comment: `console.log(data)` is already present in your code, within your ajax calls' `success:` function. Using Chrome browser, you can right click and hit "inspect", then go to the "Console" tab. If you run your code after, you should see the result of your console log. It may tell you if there's something wrong with your code, invalid data formats, etc.

Comment: console.log(data) not give me any thing meaning nothing display but console.log(companyId); is give me correct id so from browser inspect nothing data display from ajax request

Comment: so what i do to solve my issue

Comment: That is because `companyId` is defined outside the scope of your ajax call. The `data` variable contains the results of your ajax call. If `console.log(data)` within the call does not return anything, then your data source is not working. `url: '@Url.Action("GetRelatedBranches", "AddUserModel")',` might not be correct or doesn't return anything.

Comment: so from my code what is recomended url must be used please

Comment: Are there any items in `_db.Branch` that meet this criteria? `Where(p => p.CompanyNo == companyId).ToList();` If there are no matching records, that may be the cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my issue

the issue exist on URL ajax  request not correct so ajax

request not working .

after change URL ajax request it working perfect

I change URL ajax request to `url: '?handler=RelatedBranches',` and it working fine
I change my ajax request as below

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#company-select').change(function () {
                var companyId = $(this).val();
                console.log(companyId);
                if (companyId) {
                    console.log(companyId);
                    $.ajax({
                      
                        url: '?handler=RelatedBranches',
                        type: "GET",
                        dataType: "json",
                       
                        data: { companyId: companyId },
                        success: function (data) {
                            console.log(data);
                            $('#branch-select').empty();
                            $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                      
                                $('#branch-select').append($('<option>', {
                                    value: item.iBranchCode,
                                    text: item.vBranchDesc
                                }));
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
```